# PHP - while creating array (mysql_fetch_array) program creating array in array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, while-loop

I want to create array:

```
$branza_query = mysql_query ('SELECT craft FROM base') or die...   

 $craft = array();  
        while ($cra = mysql_fetch_array($craft_query))
        {
            $craft[] = $cra;
        }
```

No big deal but when i want to `print_r` it, i have restult like:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => steel [craft] => steel )
        [1] => Array ( [0] => farm [craft] => farm ) 
        [2] => Array ( [0] => some [craft] => some ) 
        [3] => Array ( [0] => it [craft] => it )    // etc.
      )
```

I just wanted to add next value to existing array with result like:

```
Array ( [0] = steel
        [1] = farm
        [2] = some
        [3] = it        /etc.
      )
```

or

```
Array ( [0] = craft => steel
        [1] = craft => farm
        [2] = craft => some
        [3] = craft => it        /etc.
      )
```

or something similar because next thing what i want to do is something like:

```
foreach($craft as $value)
{
    echo '<option value ="'.$value.'"> '.$value.'</option>';
}
```

Comment: point to the index instead, `$cra['craft']` or `$cra[0]`

Comment: so now result is: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => it [craft] => it ) [1] => Array ( [0] => farm [craft] => farm )` etc. so this doesn't solve the problem

Comment: you didn't understood my point, point to the exact element of the array, `$craft[] = $cra[0];` or `$craft[] = $cra['craft'];`

Comment: oh, i got it. Thanks a lot :) now it's working perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is you create an array take `$cra` as its first element every time you call `$craft[]=$cra`, and then add it to `$craft`. That is why you have a three layer array as result.

But actually, `$cra` is already an array. So what you need to do is just `array_push($craft, $cra);`. Or use `array_push($craft, $cra[0]);` this will give what you want.

Please refer to the page http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php